# openpyxl chage font size of title & y_axis.title

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am currently struggling with changing the font of y axis title & the charts title itself.

I have tried to create a font setting & applying it to the titles - with no luck what so ever.

```
new_chart.y_axis.title = chart_dict['y_title']
ft = Font(name='Calibri',
          size=11,
          bold = False,
          italic = False,
          vertAlign = None,
          underline = 'none',
          strike = False,
          color = 'FF000000')

new_chart.y_axis.title.font = ft
```

Is there any easy setting for this - like:

```
chart.y_axis.title.some_size_attrib = 12
```

or am I in the wrong direction?

Comment: There is no easy way to do this. See the various discussions on the openpyxl mailing list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I hope it won't get you too late. After a lot of research I was able to find a way to change the font and its size from a chart segment using Openpyxl.

The size of the font is defined at the sz=1500 and this means the usual 15 font size. Using that logic 1200 is 12. The minimum is 100 and the maximum is 400000.

```
from openpyxl.chart.text import RichText
from openpyxl.drawing.text import Paragraph, ParagraphProperties, CharacterProperties, Font    

font_test = Font(typeface='Calibri')
cp = CharacterProperties(latin=font_test, sz=1500)
chart.x_axis.txPr = RichText(p=[Paragraph(pPr=ParagraphProperties(defRPr=cp), endParaRPr=cp)])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! After a long day of search, finally found this solution! :D

Answer (score 3):

In my case that was not working properly.
The one I used in the end was:

```
from openpyxl.drawing.text import CharacterProperties

cp = CharacterProperties(sz=1100)  # Where size goes from 100 till 40000
mygraph.x_axis.title.tx.rich.p[0].r.rPr = cp
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, neither of these answers worked, so I did this:

```
from openpyxl.drawing.text import CharacterProperties, Paragraph, ParagraphProperties, RegularTextRun

cp = CharacterProperties(sz=1200)
xtStr = u"X-axis Title"
ytStr = u"Y-axis Title"
myChart.x_axis.title = ""
myChart.y_axis.title = ""
xPara = [Paragraph(pPr=ParagraphProperties(defRPr=cp), r=RegularTextRun(t=s)) for s in xtStr.split("\n")]
yPara = [Paragraph(pPr=ParagraphProperties(defRPr=cp), r=RegularTextRun(t=s)) for s in ytStr.split("\n")]
myChart.x_axis.title.tx.rich.paragraphs = xPara
myChart.y_axis.title.tx.rich.paragraphs = yPara
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code snippet to change the chart title size

```
from openpyxl.drawing.text import (
    ParagraphProperties,
    CharacterProperties,
)

def set_chart_title_size(chart, size=1400):
    paraprops = ParagraphProperties()
    paraprops.defRPr = CharacterProperties(sz=size)

    for para in chart.title.tx.rich.paragraphs:
        para.pPr=paraprops 

set_chart_title_size(chart, size=1400)
```