# Is it possible to change size font in a chart using openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, charts, openpyxl

I'm using Python version 2.7 and openpyxl version 2.4.0 on Windows. I need to change font size in a chart (in title/legend). Is it possible?  I've searched everywhere in the openpyxl documentation and online but I can't find anything.

I try to use that

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.chart import Reference, Series, LineChart, BarChart
from openpyxl.chart.text import RichText
from openpyxl.drawing.text import Paragraph, ParagraphProperties, CharacterProperties, Font

chart = BarChart()
chart.type = 'col'
chart.style = 20
chart.y_axis.title = 'Stress, MPa'
data = Reference(ws, min_col=6, min_row=2, max_row=q-1, max_col=7)
cats = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=3, max_row=q-1)
chart.add_data(data, titles_from_data=True)
chart.set_categories(cats)
chart.shape = 4

font_test = Font(typeface='Calibri')
cp = CharacterProperties(latin=font_test, sz=1500)
chart.y_axis.textProperties = RichText(p=[Paragraph(pPr=ParagraphProperties(defRPr=cp), endParaRPr=cp)])

ws.add_chart(chart, "I31")
```

When I use that I have an error in Excel ('Can't display content'). But my code passes without errors

Comment: It's not in the documentation but it is covered by the OOXML specification. You must be prepared to use this and work with the XML source.

Answer (score 1):

this is the shortest way to change font colour and size

```
list_rows_3 = []
main_heading = ['Test',' ', 'Group Name', 'Result Status', ' ', 'Count']
m1 = [ font_color(item,20,'000000') for item in main_heading ]
list_rows_3.append(m1)
```

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible

```
>>> from openpyxl.styles import colors
>>> from openpyxl.styles import Font, Color
>>> from openpyxl import Workbook
>>> wb = Workbook()
>>> ws = wb.active
>>>
>>> a1 = ws['A1']
>>> d4 = ws['D4']
>>> ft = Font(color=colors.RED)
>>> a1.font = ft
>>> d4.font = ft
>>>
>>> a1.font.italic = True # is not allowed 
>>>
>>> # If you want to change the color of a Font, you need to reassign it::
>>>
>>> a1.font = Font(color=colors.RED, italic=True) # the change only affects A1
```

source: [openpyxl documentation](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/styles.html)

Comment: I need to change font size in a CHART title, not in a cell.

Comment: sorry, you can change via chart.title.txPr property

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39054631/openpyxl-chage-font-size-of-title-y-axis-title he is changing x_axis.txPr, but this works with chart.title.txPr

Comment: The principles are similar but text formatting in charts is covered by drawingML which is much more complicated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39054631/openpyxl-chage-font-size-of-title-y-axis-title    When I use that I have an error in Excel ('Can't display content'). But my code passes without errors

Comment: Will be easier to discuss this on the mailing list, with a sample file. The API isn' t very intuitive.